# Simplifying a switch/case statement in C

Tags: c

I wrote a code to read 20 different values from 20 different addresses in C. My problem is that I only know how to do it in switch/case statement. Is there a way to simplify this code? Writing 20+ cases will make it very long.

```
float32 Voltage_Selection[20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}; 

bool Stat[20] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ,20 };     //20 status in an array

static uint8_t read = No_read;
uint16_t = answer;
void V_Read(void)
{
    typedef enum
    {
        No_read = 0, read_1, read_2, read_3, read_4, read_5, read_6, read_7, read_8, read_9, read_10, read_11, read_12, read_13, read_14, read_15, read_16, read_17, read_18, read_19, read_20;
    } read;
    
    switch (read)
    {
        case No_read;
        Read_function(NULL, Address_0) 
        break;
        
        case read 1;
        answer = Read_function(&Voltage_Selection, Address_1)
        if(answer)
            stat[1] = false;
        else
            stat[1] = true;
        break;
        
        case read 2;
        answer = Read_function(&Voltage_Selection, Address_2)
        if(answer)
            stat[2] = false;
        else
            stat[2] = true;
        break;
        
        case read 3;
        answer = Read_function(&Voltage_Selection, Address_3)
        if(answer)
            stat[3] = false;
        else
            stat[3] = true;
        break;
        
        //*** all the way till case 20 ***//

        case read 20;
        answer = Read_function(&Voltage_Selection, Address_20)
        if(answer)
            stat[20] = false;
        else
            stat[20] = true;
        break;
        default;
        break;
        
        if(read >= read_20)
        {
            read = read_1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag `C#` or `C++` as your code is not either, it is plain `C`

Comment: Use a corresponding array for the addresses. Then it collapses to one line: `Read_function(&Voltage_Selection, address_array[read])`

Comment: My apologize Cory, my first time using stackoverflow. 

Kaylum would you please show me how to do it. I'm not sure which parts to remove.. Thanks..

Comment: Why is your `bool` array `bool Stat[20]` initialized with non-bool-ish integer values? What is the intent?

Comment: I told you what to remove. Remove the entire `switch` block and replace with that one line of code. Declare the address_array as: `type address_array[20] = {Address_0, Address_1, ....};`

Comment: Thank you kaylum. Much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use an array of addresses like you have an array of `stat` values?

Comment: Hello immibis, could you clarify more on your approach. How would it look like?